# How do I permanently hide the "More" bar in a Tab Based Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

First time Stackoverflow'er here, so bear with me...

I'm working on a Tab Based Application for the iPhone, and I have encountered a problem that I've been having trouble working out. I've been searching high and low for an answer, but it's one of those problems that is difficult to phrase succinctly. That makes getting useful search results difficult.

In a nutshell, my Application will have more than five tab items in the bottom tab bar, resulting in the fifth tab item being labeled as "More...". Tapping on that item then brings up a view with a bar at the top (UINavigationBar) that says "More", and a UITableView which lists the 5th, 6th and 7th item's titles and icons.

Although I found a way to get rid of the top bar once a user has tapped on the 5th, 6th or 7th item, I would like that top "More" bar to never be displayed. In other words, the user taps on the "More..." tab item at the bottom and they see the UITableView with no bar above it. Ideally, I'd like to put my own custom header image above the list, but I just want to know if what I want to do is even possible first.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive a class from `UITabBarController`, e.g., `MyTabController`.
Use this class as tab controller, i.e., assign it in the storyboard.
Hide in the `initWithNibName` of that controller the navigation bar of the `moreNavigationController`:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
      // ... whatever you want
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationBarHidden=true;
  }
  return self;
}
```

The navigation bar won't appear.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the example code. I hadn't considered overriding the TabBarController in some way, and I didn't even realize that it contained a "moreNavigationController" property/class instance. I'll give that a try!